# Power Test with Fair and Unfair Probabilities using R

Tags: probability, statistics

Working on the following question:

Assume a roulette table has 52 numbers (26 red & 26 green). You watch the roulette table N times and observe the numbers that it picks (1-52, red or green). Your null hypothesis is that the table is fair i.e it picks red and green numbers with equal probability -- p = 0.5. The alternative hypothesis is that it is not fair and picks red more often -- p = 0.5005. Assuming a significance level of 1%, how large does N have to be to have a test with power of 90% against the alternative that p = 0.5005?

My work so far in R:

```
meannull <- 0.5000
sdnull <- 0.5000
meanalt1 <- 0.5005

ene <- 50 # N observations
statse <- sdnull/sqrt(ene) ## Calculating Standard Error

xseq <- seq(3,3, len=1001)
densitynull <- dnorm(xseq, meannull, statse)
densityalt1 <- dnorm(xseq, meanalt1, statse)

## Plotting the sampling distributions ##
plot(xseq, densitynull, type='l')
lines(xseq, densityalt1, col='blue')
abline(v=meannull+1.96*statse, col='red')
abline(v=meannull-1.96*statse, col='red')

1 - pnorm(meannull+1.96*statse, meanalt1, statse) ## Want Power of 90%!
```

Not sure about the two means I've used -- am I correct in assuming that that both the mean and sd will be 0.5 under the null and 0.5005 under the alt?

Comment: $50$ looks rather small.  I would guess several million

Answer (score 0):

The mean of a Bernoulli distribution is $p$ and the standard deviation is $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$

- When $p=0.5$ these are indeed $0.5$ and $0.5$
- When $p=0.5005$ these are $0.5005$ and about $0.49999975$

In general the standard deviation can never exceed $0.5$